# How do I analyze the memory dump I created with Game Guardian?

Tags: android, eclipse, memory, analyzer, memory-dump

I dump the memory of processes running on Android. I did it with GameGuardian. But how do I analyze this. 
It contains .bin files and a .txt file. Eclipse Memory Analyzer does not analyze this.

Answer (score 0):

`.bin` files contains raw data from memory. File name pointed which area stored here.

`.txt` file contain list of all mapped region from kernel with their labels and rights.

Use any suitable for you HEX viewer for view and work with data.

Comment: Can you share a sample document or video? @Enyby

Comment: @SemraÖZKAYA No. But you can get it by self. GG work on any Android device include most of know Android emulators for PC. Install emulator and make dump on it. Genymotion, LDPlayer, Nox and so on.

Comment: I have to learn how to do it so that I can do it by myself